# When I activate Render Whitespace in VS Code it changes rtl text to ltr

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem which is when I activate render whitespace in vs code it changes my rtl text and will show it in ltr direction, here are some photo to better demonstrate this:

[image]

and then when I turn off whitespace rendering It shows correctly:

[image]

I Really like the dots which are showing when I turn whitespace rendering on...

Comment: I created an issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90019 , vote it up if you have the same problem